# Can't compile static qt project with webkit

Tags: qt, webkit, static-linking

Hi All I compiled [qt static build and everything works fine](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW). But when I am trying to compile qt project which includes:

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

I got an error:

```
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
```

is it possible to compile static qt project with webkit?

Comment: How do you point to that static Qt build in your system?

Comment: It appears the webkit module gets skipped in a static build. I looked at the `configure` file in the `qtbase` source directory and found on line 6431 `echo "Warning: Using static linking will disable the Webkit module."`

Answer (score 1):

Webkit is not built in static Qt builds. It is not possible to use the webkit module in a static Qt build.

It is also not possible to use the webkit module dll from a dynamic build, because it needs to link with Qt, and your statically linked executable doesn't export any Qt symbols. It of course could, but that's a whole different can of worms.

Comment: @Gray The question required a yes/no answer, and I gave such.

Comment: @KubaOber Apologies then. It honestly looked like a comment to me. I think your edit makes it a much better answer. If I saw your rep/experience here, I probably would have voted differently. To me, it looked like the kind of **comment** I would make, then downvote a post/recommend for removal. But I think I just misunderstood.