# Is it possible to compile Qt with static flag and have QtWebKit included ? (Windows)

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

Similar question was asked over 5 years ago, and at the time it seemed to be impossible (QT 4.7). Has anything changed? Can I do it in QT 5.6? I'd like to have all QT libs like QTCore, QTGui etc to be static libraries but still have support for QtWebKit. I'm ok with WebKit being a dynamic library itself, in which case it has to link against already built QT static libraries. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't compile static qt project with webkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723051/cant-compile-static-qt-project-with-webkit)

Comment: Keep in mind that the open-source license (GPL or LGPL) will affect your code when linking statically. Therefore, you'll have to release your source code under the same license to any end-user (i.e., whoever will receive the binary - in any form).